# Visual Studio 2015 - MVC 4 - Razor compile errors

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

Since updating to Visual Studio 2015 Update 1, my MVC 4 project has compile errors in several view files. The errors are related to the following:

- For loops (you must declare a type for the temporary variable or it is not recognized)
- Linq expressions are not recongized (For example: Orderby is not a member of List(Of String))
- Html.DisplayFor is not recognized (Reference required to assembly 'System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' containing the type 'Expression(Of )'. Add one to your project.)

Other than these 3 type of errors, the intellisense in vbhtml files seems fine. And in VS2013 none of the above was an issue so these errors did not exist before updating.

According to [this post](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt591926.aspx), it sounds like my version of Visual Studio should have this resolved. I have tried adding a reference to System.Core but I get an error that it has already added. I also tried deleting the 14.0 folder from the AppData folder but that didn't help. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried simply a clean and rebuild all to your solution?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately the errors are still there. If I run the project it doesn't actually error out, just an intellisense problem, which makes me think it is related to the bug in VS 2015 that was supposed to be fixed in my version because that's how it was described.

Comment: might have to do with the versions you're referencing in your web.config and your Views\web.config files..   make sure the numbers match up with what your project references are.

Comment: I was able to fix the compiler errors by adding a reference to System.Core (<add assembly="System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>) but that causes the website to not actually load, because of the error - Could not load file or assembly System.Core. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in Visual Studio 2017. I was able to fix it by updating the version numbers for System.Web.Mvc in the `<pages>` section of Views\web.config to match the version referenced by the project. Thanks to JamieD77's comment for pointing in the right direction.